# How change the display label for a foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have `Employee` with gender_id being FK to a `Gender` table. And using EF to generate the classes to access the db.

I create a MetaData type so I could change the label display on the page.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeMetaData))] 
public partial class Employee
{
}

public class EmployeeMetaData
{
    [Display(Name = "Nombre2")]
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Apellido")]
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Sexo")]
    public Nullable<int> gender_id { get; set; }
}
```

But the `gender_id` doesn't change as you can see on the picture.

[image]

So I thought also would need create a MetaData for `Gender` but still doesnt show on the page.

This is the autogenerated View, `last_name` works ok, but `gender_id` doesnt

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.last_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.last_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.last_name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gender_id, "gender_id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("gender_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.gender_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SeanLange You are right, I add it together with the Entity Framework tag because is the db Im using

Comment: This is a classic case of your entity model not matching the needs of the view.  Create a view model with just the gender_id and a list of SelectItem's for your genders. place the DisplayName attribute on the gender_id property and user DropDownListFor passing the gender_id and select list.

Comment: @Fran can you point me to a more precise example. Im not sure what you mean. Im using EF to autogenerate the views, and then modify them to match the needs.

Comment: I'm saying work you way back from the view.  Creates view model that matches the requirements of your view.  Map your view model to your entity model.  You can use automapper here, but generally not exposing your domain model to the world.  it quickly becomes difficult to satisfy both your screen requirements and your entity requirements as comlexity builds.  you also run into [overposting] (https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETOverpostingMassAssignmentModelBindingSecurity.aspx).  just search SO for viewmodels, there are a number of Q/A's on the site.

Answer (score 3):

After adding the autogenerated View code to the question realize the problem is the `LabelFor` also include the name of the label.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.gender_id, 
               "gender_id", 
               htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }
              )
```

After remove `"gender_id"` LabelFor start using the MetaData alias.

> Of course this will bring the problem if I autogenerate the view again, the changes will be lost.